# Python: write outer product using map and reduce

Tags: python, numpy, functional-programming, mapreduce

Suppose I have a matrix

```
import numpy as np
from functools import reduce
np.random.seed(123)
X = np.random.normal(size=(5, 2))
```

and I want to compute X^t X without using numpy functions and using `map`, `reduce` and `lambda` functions. Since we can write X^t X as a sum of outer products, my goal would be:

```
def outer_product(x):
    """Computes outer product of a vector with itself"""
    pass

map(outer_product, X)
```

However I can't seem to find an efficient way of writing all of these with map reduce.

## My Attempt

```
def outer(x):
    xxx = np.repeat(x, len(x))
    yyy = np.array(list(x) * len(x))
    return np.reshape(list(map(lambda x, y: x*y, xxx, yyy)), (len(x), len(x)))
```

so that

```
outer(X[0, ])
```

And then I've written the covariance matrix as follows

```
def cov(X):
    return np.array(reduce(lambda x, y: x + y, list(map(outer, X)))) / np.size(X, 0)
```

Comment: Can you find an *inefficient* way that you could possibly optimize afterwards?

Comment: Yes, but it's _seriously_ horrible. I'll post it

Comment: Actually I'm not sure it works now

Comment: @ScottHunter I've added it!

Comment: Is this just a programming exercise, or do you really need something more efficient than `numpy`?  It is clear what `numpy` function(s) you are trying to avoid, what you can use.  `map` and `reduce` are Python level iterators, best used with Python lists.  Iteration on arrays is less efficient.

Comment: Yes basically I wanted to write PCA using `map` and `reduce`!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, outer product can be defined as nested map such as

```
outer = lambda V: np.array(list(map(lambda x: list(map(lambda y: x*y, V)), V)))

X = np.random.normal(size=(5, 2))
>>> outer(X[1])
array([[ 0.08007683, -0.42624902], [-0.42624902,  2.26892377]])
```

Actually, it is simpler to use list comprehension

```
outer = lambda V: np.array([[x*x1 for a in V] for x1 in V])
```

will give you same result. Then you can map to your matrix like

```
>>> list(map(outer, X))
[array([[ 1.17859381, -1.08274874],
       [-1.08274874,  0.99469794]]), array([[ 0.08007683, -0.42624902],
       [-0.42624902,  2.26892377]]), array([[ 0.33477825, -0.9555216 ],
       [-0.9555216 ,  2.72724264]]), array([[5.88877215, 1.04083337],
       [1.04083337, 0.18396604]]), array([[ 1.60259461, -1.0972381 ],
       [-1.0972381 ,  0.75123892]])]
```

Your reduce part is quite nice and concise by the way. I don't think that part requires any further refactoring.

Answer (score 1):

```
In [40]: X = np.arange(10).reshape(5,2)
```

Using the `outer` and list/map from the accepted answer:

```
In [41]: outer = lambda V: np.array([[x*x1 for x in V] for x1 in V])                     
In [43]: list(map(outer, X))                                                             
Out[43]: 
[array([[0, 0],
        [0, 1]]),
 array([[4, 6],
        [6, 9]]),
 array([[16, 20],
        [20, 25]]),
 array([[36, 42],
        [42, 49]]),
 array([[64, 72],
        [72, 81]])]
```

Using `numpy` broadcasting:

```
In [44]: X[:,:,None]*X[:,None,:]                                                         
Out[44]: 
array([[[ 0,  0],
        [ 0,  1]],

       [[ 4,  6],
        [ 6,  9]],

       [[16, 20],
        [20, 25]],

       [[36, 42],
        [42, 49]],

       [[64, 72],
        [72, 81]]])
```

For a (5,2) `X` the result is a (5,2,2) array.

Some small time tests:

```
In [55]: timeit list(map(outer, X))                                                      
51.8 µs ± 1.29 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [57]: timeit [outer(i) for i in X]                                                    
49.8 µs ± 65.9 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [58]: timeit X[:,:,None]*X[:,None,:]                                                  
5.37 µs ± 11.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

`list/map` has about the same speed as a list comprehension.  Generally I find list comprehensions to be clearer.  But broadcasted numpy operations are usually much faster.

If you are going to iterate, consider working with a lists; it's usually faster:

```
In [61]: timeit [outer(i) for i in X.tolist()]                                           
24.3 µs ± 63.6 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 10000 loops each)
In [62]: outer0 = lambda V: [[x*x1 for x in V] for x1 in V] 
In [64]: timeit [outer0(i) for i in X.tolist()]                                          
7.33 µs ± 16 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```